# How to save multiple numbers with one NSUserDefaults?

Tags: xcode, save, nsuserdefaults

At the end of my board, I want to save the level, board points, and total points into one NSUserDefaults, then recall and break the numbers back out.  Is this possible?  Just trying not to have a list of NSUserDefaults each time.

Example:

```
int level = 35
int boardPoints = 500
int totalPoints = 18000
```

I would want to save a "levelValue" with all three, maybe with a period delimiter?
levelValue = 35.500.18000;

```
// Save value
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:levelValue forKey:@"levelValueKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

// Recall
// Somehow recall Left(levelValueKey,2), Mid(starting from period,2), and right(up to period)
level = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"levelValueKey"];
boardPoints = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"levelValueKey"];
totalPoints = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"levelValueKey"];
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save all you ints as an NSArray in NSUserDefaults instead, like this:

```
//your ints
int level = 35;
int boardPoints = 500;
int totalPoints = 18000;

//put ints in array
NSArray *levelValueArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:level], [NSNumber numberWithInt:boardPoints], [NSNumber numberWithInt:totalPoints], nil]
//save in NSUserDefaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:levelValueArray forKey:@"levelValueKey"];

//retreive
NSArray *arrayLevelValues = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"levelValueKey"];
```

To use them:

```
NSLog(@"arrayLevelValues: %@", arrayLevelValues[1]);
//the object 1 is a string so you'll need to convert it to int using intValue
int tempPoints = [arrayLevelValues[1] intValue];
NSLog(@"tempPoints: %d",tempPoints);
```

Comment: I get two errors on the: NSArray *levelValueArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:level, boardPoints, totalPoints, nil];     Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'id' and Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

Comment: That works perfect!  I'm trying to retrieve the individual values.  The first NSLog works, but I'm not sure how to save the value?   NSLog(@"arrayLevelValues: %@", arrayLevelValues[1]);      
    
    int tempPoints = arrayLevelValues[1];
    NSLog(@"tempPoints: %d",tempPoints);Also, I'm using an NSInteger for 64-bit, will that effect the NSNumber in the array?

Comment: Also, I'm using an NSInteger for 64-bit and changed the numberwithInt to numberWithLong.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: That worked.  If I use NSInteger level = 35, the warning is "Implict conversion loses interger precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int'     I tried changing the numberwithInt to numberWithLong but then it returns 0?

Comment: I answered my own question.  If you use NSInteger, you need to use NSNumber numberWithLong.